# IIS 7.5 - Setting up a Virtual Directory for a file share on another domain

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cross-domain, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.  I'd like to set up a virtual directory for my website to allow the download of video files from a file share on a server in another domain.  I have a domain username and password that allows me to access this file share.  However, when I try to setup the virtual directory in IIS, I get the following error message:

> ### HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the     page is invalid.
>
> - **Module:** IIS Web Core
> - **Notification:** `BeginRequest`
> - **Handler:** Not yet determined
> - **Error Code:** `0x8007052e`
> - **Config Error:** Cannot read configuration file
> - **Config File:** `\\?\UNC\z27ar1cfvs004.abc.se\video$\web.config`
> - **Requested URL:** http://localhost:8080/Video
> - **Physical Path:** `\\z27ar1cfvs004.abc.se\video$`
> - **Logon Method:** Not yet determined
> - **Logon User:** Not yet determined

Weirdly, I can hit Explore on my virtual directory and IIS will launch Explorer showing me the files.

For my site's authentication settings I have Basic and Windows authentication settings enabled.

Here are the things I've tried unsuccessfully:

- Changing the Connect As... user for the site to use the domain user credentials
- Changing the Connect As... user for the virtual directory to use the domain user credentials
- Changing the Application Pool identity for the website to use the domain user account credentials
- Creating a local user account on the IIS server with the same username/password as on the domain server, and trying all 3 steps above again but only specifying the username rather than domain\username
- Changing the Managed Pipeline Mode: neither Integrated nor Classic makes any difference

I've Googled until my eyes have gone blurry and spent hours trying many recommended suggestions but all to no avail.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you get around this? I have a similar problem where I need cross domain authenticated access to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a couple ways around this, depending on what your problem is:

- Actually make a `web.config` file in the shared directory.
- Make a `<location path="video" inheritInChildApplications="false" />` element in your main `web.config` to specify that the virtual directory is not allowed to have `web.config` settings override its parent.
- Set up a real directory in your website that *does* have a `web.config` in it, and use the URL Rewrite tool to make a set of rewrites to the actual content.
- If you have written a custom HTTP Module that is enabled for the site, turn it off for that directory. For instance, if the module does not have to run on static files, add `precondition="managedHandler"` to its settings in `web.config` or `applicationHost.config`.